# How to pass JSON Object as argument to python script via C# process?

Tags: python, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to pass JSON object to python script through process but the script receives the JSON object in a wrong format the keys of the object without double or single quotes like the following:

```
{path:C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\myfile.txt,models:[{Id:5014,Name:e,Type:2},{Id:2,Name:r1,Type:1}]}
```

C# process code:

```
 var script = "D:\\python\\pythonscript.py";
 var objectJson = new ObjectJson()
 {
     path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\myfile.txt",
     models = models
 };

 var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectJson);
 Console.WriteLine(x);

 psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"\"\"{x}\"\"\"";
 Console.WriteLine(psi.Arguments);
 psi.UseShellExecute = false;
 psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
 psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

 var errors = "";
 var results = "";

 using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
 {
     errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
     results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
     process.WaitForExit();
 }
```

Josn object in C# code is :

```
{"path":"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\myfile.txt","models":[{"Id":5014,"Name":"e","Type":2},{"Id":2,"Name":"r1","Type":1}]}
```

Python code gives me error at data.models that there is no attribute called models in data

```
dataObj = sys.argv[1]
data = json.loads(dataObj)
models = data.models
```

When passing process arguments like the following:

```
 psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{x}\"";
```

python script gives an error at line json.loads(dataObj) that json decoder can't convert it to json cause it expect name between double quotes.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Whats the output of Console.WriteLine(x);

Comment: @SelakaNanayakkara I've edited the question to include the JSON object in C#

Comment: I have posted an answer check that. Also remove the model and see if it passes the path properly

Answer (score 1):

**Try passing like below :**

```
   List<Item> jsonObject = new List<Item>
    {
            
            new Item { Name = "key1", Value = "value1" },
            new Item { Name = "key2 ", Value = "value2" }
    };


    using Newtonsoft.Json;
   
    
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemList, Formatting.Indented);
```

**In you process in C# try passing like below :**

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = pythonPath,
        Arguments = $"{scriptPath} \"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonString)}\"", // Pass JSON string as an argument
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
    {
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

**In your python code :**

```
import sys
import json

json_string = sys.argv[1]

json_object = json.loads(json_string)

print(json_object['key1'])
print(json_object['key2'])
```

**Check if the values key1 and key2 were received without any error. If so you can create a class Serialize object in C# properly and pass it to the shell script.**

What happens is that python actually complains that it is not valid JSON. In your case This is NOT VALID :

```
    {
    "path":"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\myfile.txt",
    "models":[
       {"Id":5014,"Name":"e","Type":2},
       {"Id":2,"Name":"r1","Type":1}
      ]
    }
```

**This is VALID :**

```
{
  "path": "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\myfile.txt",
  "models": [
    {
      "Id": "5014",
      "Name": "e",
      "Type": "2"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Name": "r1",
      "Type": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it gives json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: This is on python side right?

Comment: yes, it raises when executing this line json.loads(json_string)

Comment: Got the problem updated the answer check now

Comment: I got this error Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 3 (char 5). I've serialized the object again before send it to the script and it did work.

Answer (score 1):

I've passed the arguments as follows and I'm not sure that this is the best solution but it works

```
psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)}\"";
```